# No Module Named 'django_python3_ldap'

Tags: python, django, active-directory, ldap

I would like to authenticate users using an Active Directory. In order to support this functionality in my project, I am using the framework 'django-python3-ldap'. However, I am receiving the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_python3_ldap'`. If you need anymore information, please let me know.

**global_settings.py**

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django_python3_ldap.auth.LDAPBackend']
```

**setting.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',

'website', 'django_python3_ldap',
]

# Authentication Backend

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('django_python3_ldap.auth.LDAPBackend',)

# Django-Python3-LDAP Authentication

LDAP_AUTH_URL = "ldap://<my_domain>.com:389"

LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASE = "ou=people,dc=<my_domain>,dc=com"

LDAP_AUTH_OBJECT_CLASS = "inetOrgPerson"

LDAP_AUTH_USER_FIELDS = {
    "username": "sAMAccountName",
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail",
}

LDAP_AUTH_USER_LOOKUP_FIELDS = ("username",)

LDAP_AUTH_CLEAN_USER_DATA = "django_python3_ldap.utils.clean_user_data"

LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_USERNAME =  "django_python3_ldap.utils.format_username_active_directory"
```

Comment: first thought - check whether the library was installed in the same environment  that is used for running your project. maybe installation failed in the middle and you've missed that? try to use `manage.py shell` and then `import django_python3_ldap` to check again

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov the library is located inside the correct environment, however, I get this warning during installation: `retrying 1.3.3 has requirement six>=1.7.0, but you'll have six 1.4.1 which is incompatible.
pyasn1-modules 0.2.2 has requirement pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.1, but you'll have pyasn1 0.3.2 which is incompatible.
python-ldap 3.1.0 has requirement pyasn1>=0.3.7, but you'll have pyasn1 0.3.2 which is incompatible.`

Comment: and what about second point? is it importable in shell? maybe it is caused by six version and ModuleNotFoundError is hiding another exception